# Cognitive Text Anaytics with Databricks in PySpark: Mixing string and dictionary/object document input unsupported

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-services

I have the following text in my dummy.txt

> "Redmond is a city in King County, Washington, United States, located
> 15 miles east of Seattle."

The document has been uploaded to my datalake folder "/dbfs/mnt/lake/RAW/export/dummy.txt"

I read in the data with the following code:

```
with open("/dbfs/mnt/lake/RAW/export/dummy.txt", "rb") as fd:
    documents = fd.read()
```

I then apply cognitive text analytics on the data in the dummy.txt file with the following:

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient

credential = AzureKeyCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
endpoint= "https://xxxxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint, credential)


response = text_analytics_client.extract_key_phrases(documents, language="en")
result = [doc for doc in response if not doc.is_error]

for doc in result:
    print(doc.key_phrases)
```

I should get the following:

```
['King County', 'United States', 'Redmond', 'city', 'Washington', 'Seattle']
```

But I get the following Type-error:

```
Mixing string and dictionary/object document input unsupported
```

Can someone let me know what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the client library with:

```
pip install azure-ai-textanalytics==5.1.0
```

Create a new Python file and copy the code below. Remember to replace the key variable with the key for your resource and replace the endpoint variable with the endpoint for your resource.

```
key = "paste-your-key-here"
endpoint = "paste-your-endpoint-here"

from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

# Authenticate the client using your key and endpoint 
def authenticate_client():
    ta_credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
    text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(
            endpoint=endpoint, 
            credential=ta_credential)
    return text_analytics_client

    client = authenticate_client()

    def key_phrase_extraction_example(client):

    try:
        documents = ["My cat might need to see a veterinarian."]

        response = client.extract_key_phrases(documents = documents)[0]

        if not response.is_error:
            print("\tKey Phrases:")
            for phrase in response.key_phrases:
                print("\t\t", phrase)
        else:
            print(response.id, response.error)

    except Exception as err:
        print("Encountered exception. {}".format(err))
        
    key_phrase_extraction_example(client)
```

Output –

```
Key Phrases:
    cat
    veterinarian
```

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/key-phrase-extraction/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-python

Comment: Abhishek, thanks for this. Could I ask if it would possible to show me how to retrieve the output in a CSV or table?