# Azure Form Recognizer Not Finding Content with Python on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-services

I am executing the following Python on Databricks with the relevant Cognitive Form recognizer libraries:

```
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
credential = AzureKeyCredential("aaa6123af5b843a38044538d95584c3d")
endpoint= "https://myformrecognizr.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"

form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(endpoint, credential)

with open("/dbfs/mnt/lake/RAW/export/Picturehouse.pdf", "rb") as fd:
    form = fd.read()

poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_content(form)
form_pages = poller.result()

for content in form_pages:
    for table in content.tables:
        print("Table found on page {}:".format(table.page_number))
        print("Table location {}:".format(table.bounding_box))
        for cell in table.cells:
            print("Cell text: {}".format(cell.text))
            print("Location: {}".format(cell.bounding_box))
            print("Confidence score: {}\n".format(cell.confidence))

    if content.selection_marks:
        print("Selection marks found on page {}:".format(content.page_number))
        for selection_mark in content.selection_marks:
            print("Selection mark is '{}' within bounding box '{}' and has a confidence of {}".format(
                selection_mark.state,
                selection_mark.bounding_box,
                selection_mark.confidence
            ))
```

The pdf form looks like the following:

[image]

The libraries recognizes
Cell text: Item
Cell text: Qty
Cell text: Seat Allocation
Cell text: Subtotal
Cell text: Adult
Cell text: 1
Cell text: D-11
Cell text: 14.50

But it doesn't recognize the following text from the pdf:

> You can go straight to the screen by showing your e-ticket to an
> usher. Alternatively, you can collect your tickets at Box Office at
> least 15 minutes before the advertised start time of the film or
> event. You need your Booking Reference and/or payment card to help us
> find your booking. You can print this page by clicking the "Print This
> Page" link above.

Is that by design? Or am I missing something in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the design is like that. The **form recognizer** is working on pre-trained models and that can recognize the key-value pairs, text, and tables from your documents and the table contents in the file uploaded as the input. Even though the file contains a large amount of text in paragraphs and table content in the middle or at any place, it will be recognized.

To know more details please **Refer** this link:

https://www.drware.com/extract-data-from-pdfs-using-form-recognizer-with-code-or-without/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBQO4QdUp6A&t=10s

https://github.com/tomweinandy/form_recognizer_demo

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need. Do you think the link will also help with my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304994/cognitive-text-anaytics-with-databricks-in-pyspark-mixing-string-and-dictionary

Comment: Yes, these links will be useful for other question too  : )